# permutation and combination advanced

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, puzzle

I have n sets having values less than 100.
I need to find how many arrangements could be made if I pick one element from each set such that in the given arrangement there are no duplicates? 
NOTE: A set can have no duplicate itself( set's property) and it can have maximum 100 elements.

Example: if n = 3
set 1= { 3 4 5 }
set 2= { 1 }
set 3= { 1 3 5}

Possible arrangements =  {3 1 5} {4 1 3} {4 1 5} {5 1 3}

hence my answer is 4.

Comment: Just wanted to clarify something: The sets have a maximum of 100 elements and the elements themselves are integers less than 100?

Comment: This question has already been asked three times (at least) on this site. Use the inclusion-exclusion principle. Stop.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio thanks i will try that . @ BeaumontTaz yes , the elements are themselves less than 100

Comment: can anyone give a solution example ?

Comment: @ratish Yet another variant on the active contest problem http://codechef.com/AUG14/problems/TSHIRTS .  We'll give an example sometime after August 15.  Please stop asking contest problems.

Comment: @deinst ok . will wait for the answer after 15 Aug .

Comment: Still no answer ? the competition ended long back